# Cannot login to Paypal sandbox with first account, but second, third account work

Tags: authentication, passwords, sandbox

I'm always told I write "biblical length" emails, but hey, I'm trying to characterize the situation the best I can for ya.

I created my sandbox.   The Business account was auto created.  I created a Personal account.
I successfully paid to the Business account with the Personal account with my Buy-now setup and my IPN works correctly (after changing the fsockopen to use SSL, changing \n to \r\n, etc).  No problems with the "front side" of all the account business.

Part of the "Backend" needs are to transfer some of the Business account money to another account after 3 days (my Business account is a middle-man).

I switched from Firefox to Chrome.  I had done all the account setups in FF, so I didn't want to try to have two logins running under one browser, sandbox or not.

I tried to login as the Business account and it failed and ended up in the "make sure your email and password are correct" loop.

I tried to login with the Personal account (the one which successfully paid into the Business account via the application).  Same error.

I tried changing the password on the original Business account, flushed cache/cookies, still cannot login.  There should not be any password errors because the accounts have the same password!!!   I cannot use the "forgot my password" logic to see what it thinks my password is, because the email is fake and it won't get sent anywhere.

I created a second Business account, and I tried to login and it logged in correctly and showed my balance correctly.  I logged out and tried the other two accounts, but the only one that ever logs in is the second Business account.

I could solve the issue by changing the target of my front side Business transfers to the second Business account, because I know I can log into that one, but that would be condoning the fact that the system is flawed, and I'd rather push this issue to find out what is wrong.

I switched to IE (argh!)
I tried the original Business account.  Failed.
I tried the Personal account.  WORKED!!!!
I tried the second Business account.  WORKED !!!! and I didn't have to flush cache or cookies.  It still won't allow the original Business account, even with IE.

I don't have time to wait 2 hours (in case it's the "too many times" problem).  There was nothing wrong with the account/passwords in the first place, and since I'd never tried logging in with any of the accounts directly before, there was no history of failed transactions.

I switched to Safari.
Once again, original Business account fails, but the other two accounts work correctly!!!!

I switched back to Chrome.
Again, original Business account fails, but the other two accounts work correctly!!!!

So, it appears once I have successfully used an account, it will work regardless of the browser, cookies or cache.  IE, Chrome and Safari all work with two accounts but none of them work with the original Business account.

Finally, I tried changing the password again for the original Business account.  Still doesn't work.

My suggestion is to add a button to the "test accounts" setup page, "LOGIN AS" and just let us automatically login as that user (after first successfully logging into the sandbox with our validated paypal account) and bypass the whole password thing, if you aren't going to get it to work.

Comment: The question may be long but you left out what kind of accounts you are talking about. Is it for your phone? Or some web site? what?

Comment: the accounts are Sandbox Business and Personal accounts for use in validating the software prior to going live.

Comment: I Googled "sandbox business account" and found no company called "Sandbox"

Comment: Really?  Did you search "sandbox" in this forum, because this forum is for questions regarding the www.SANDBOX.paypal.com interface "sandbox" as in TEST AREA for debugging problems with either user code, or for showing problems in the paypal software itself.

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

1) Apparently I should have used "Paypal" in the initial title, I had assumed the tool was already in a Paypal specific sub-forum (wrong) and I have added the word to the title.  Sorry for the confusion.

2) To answer my own question ...

I tried to login to the orig. Business account first thing this morning and it worked.  I tried to do a transfer and it wanted login validation and failed again and again.  If your results do not prove out your premise, then there is probably something wrong with your original premise in the first place, right?   So I went back to my original course of action, which was to switch from Firefox to Chrome when I went to login (because I didn't think someone would have you logging in as two different users within the same window).  WRONG AGAIN.  I logged in as Developer, but instead of going to a different window or browser, I logged in a second time by using the "Enter Sandbox" link, and was able to succesfully login with each of the accounts.

You ***have*** to be logged in as a developer in the top portion of the sandbox interface window, ***while*** you login as one of the Business or Personal accounts in the lower half of the test window or else it doesn't work.    If that is the case, and I am now doing it as it was designed, then that would explain why it was failing when trying to login when using Chrome/Safari/IE, since I wasn't logged in as the Developer account in those browsers.   Why it did occasionally PASS is crazy.  Software should be consistent, if anything.